# Where to find data on primary schools in wales?

Tags: primary-schooler, school

I am starting to look for a good primary school for my son, I have found a ton of data for schools in England that would allow me to make an informed choice, However I live in Wales and there doesn't seem to be any data available at all for welsh primary schools.

Does anyone know where this data is or if it even exists or even why its so hard to find ?

Comment: I don't know about Wales specifically, but it's my understanding that many jurisdictions are reluctant to release this kind of data. The concern is that it's counter-productive to education. I assume you've seen [this site](https://statswales.wales.gov.uk/Catalogue/Education-and-Skills/Schools-and-Teachers), but there isn't much to go by!

Comment: ...Actually, I just read [this statement](http://wales.gov.uk/about/cabinet/cabinetstatements/2012/primaryschoolbanding/;jsessionid=9563D11EAFBEE08C7323FCC52AA0E8D0?lang=en) from the Welsh gov't. "Banding" (their particular method of ranking schools) was only applied to secondary schools and not primary for reasons stated in the link.

Comment: What kind of "data" are you looking for? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Ask at your local library - they are experts at finding local data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found this site

http://mylocalschool.wales.gov.uk/

which had a lot of data and was very helpful. I am amazed that there are people that think keeping us ignorant about the performance of our schools helps education.